# Can't access javascript-object properties via angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't access javascript object properties within angularjs.

I have the following html to show a dropdown-list with all provinces loaded from angular http-call:

```
$http.get("http://myRestUrl/province").then(function(response)
{
  $scope.provinces = angular.fromJson(response.data);
});

<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedProvince">
  <option value="" selected>Bundesland auswählen</option>
  <option ng-repeat="province in provinces" value="{{province}}">
    {{province.name}}
  </option>
</select>

{{selectedProvince}} <!-- Output the Object -->
{{selectedProvince.cities}} <!-- Output nothing -->
```

The province object looks like this:

```
{"id":1,"name":"North Rhine-Westphalia","nation":{"id":1,"name":"Germany"},"cities":
[{"id":1,"name":"MÃ¼nster","province":{"id":1,"name":"North Rhine-Westphalia"}},
{"id":2,"name":"Rinkerode", "province":{"id":1,"name":"North Rhine-Westphalia"}}]}
```

Access `{{selectedProvince.name}}` or any other property is empty result aswell.

selectedProvince is defined in $scope!

Someone has any idea how i can access this data?

Comment: Guess that's due to your HTTP-call. It returns a promise. using `.then()` on your HTTP response may solve your problem, but I'm not totally sure to be honest. Just worth an attempt.

Comment: Is your `selectedProvince` a string? Does `JSON.parse(selectedProvince)` then allow you to access the properties?

Comment: `value="{{province}}"` will not work properly because it will render your whole object as a string. Look at [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Answer (score 0):

`value="{{province}}"` will not work properly because it will render your whole object as a string.
For non-string values, you need to look at [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

This should work for you:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedProvince"
  ng-options="province.name for province in provinces">
  <option value="" selected>Bundesland auswählen</option>
</select>
```